# What is the difference of chat and superchat subprotocol in WebSocket

Tags: websocket

I can't find anything about the subprotocol used with WebSockets. What is the difference between "chat" and "superchat" subprotocol mentioned in the [rfc6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) and where can I find the RFC for "chat" and "superchat" or are they just placeholders?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both protocols don't exist, so there's no actual difference between them.

These "protocols" were just example name for possible `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header values.

It's pretty much the same as using `foo` and `bar` as example names, except they chose `chat` and `superchat` as example names.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, those two names were just meant as examples. The protocol header itself is completely optional, but meant to provide a way to document what sort of dialogue/application this connection is supposed to handle.

In *what seems to me* to perhaps be a bit of over-engineering or *premature bureaucracy*, the relevant but "non-normative" [RFC section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-11.5) in fact goes to length establishing an [IANA registry of WebSocket Subprotocols](https://www.iana.org/assignments/websocket/websocket.xml#subprotocol-name). What seems to confuse people is that `chat` and `superchat` are not listed there.